# MYSQL table to search heighest salary

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `e_name`, `e_salary`, `m_id`) VALUES 
(1, 'Goat' , 500, 3), 
(2, 'Dog'  , 700, 4), 
(3, 'Rat'  , 200, 6), 
(4, 'Fox'  , 300, 3), 
(5, 'Camel', 900, 1), 
(6, 'Lion' , 200, 1);
```

e_name->employee name, e_salary->employee salary, m_id->manager id,

I would like to select the names of those employees whose salary is more than that of their manager.

I have already tried

```
select `e_salary` from `emp` where `id`= (select `m_id` from `table` group by `m_id`)
```

Comment: Where is manager's salary?

Comment: Your recent edit rendered the question unanswerable.  If the employee IDs are all `NULL` we can't do the join.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I guess the employee ids are null in the inserts to generate the auto_increment ids.

Comment: @Ullas you can get the manager's salary by self joining the table on itself using the manager's id.

Answer (score 0):

You have to self-join the employee table on itsef using the manager's id to get the manager's salary:

```
select t1.id, t1.e_name, t1.salary
from table t1
inner join table t2 on t1.m_id=t2.id
where t1.salary>t2.salary
```

Change the inner join to left join if you want to include those employees, where the manager is not set. You need to change the where condition as `t1.salary>coalesce(t2.salary,0)` as well in this case.